# PHP class to include content in Div

Tags: php, class, oop, html

I have created a class to build up the content in my page. I want to use this a broad as possible. Where I run into, is how to enclose certain content within (for example) a div, without the need for calling a closing tag.

Below is a section of my class, which does the following:

- __construct -> Creates the "" section (closed when ->Display() is called). This to keep each section in their own  tag
- AddHeader -> creates the header within the
- AddContent -> creates the div in which all the content should be kept.
- Display -> closes the  and  and allows it to be echo'd.

What I don't want is to keep calling the AddContent for every piece of content, but would like to add the content via various options like 'AddGraph', 'AddTable', which will be added to the content section. Also besides the header, potential tabs could be added, so adding the  after the header tag is not an option.

Any good suggestions and/or source which would help me further?

```
<?php
class PageContent {
    var $content;

    function __construct($class= NULL) {
        $this->content = "\n<article". (!empty($class) ? " class='". $class ."'" : "") .">\n";
        //$this->content = "\n<div". (!empty($class) ? ' class=\"$class\"' : '') .">\n";
    }

    function AddHeader($naam, $class= NULL){
        $this->content .= "<header><h3". (!empty($class) ? " class='". $class ."'" : "") .">". $naam ."</h3></header>\n";
    }

    function AddContent($class= NULL){
        $this->content .= "<div". (!empty($class) ? " class='". $class ."'" : "") .">\n";
    }

    function Display() {
        $this->content .= "<div class='clear'></div>\n";
        $this->content .= "</div>\n";
        $this->content .= "</article>\n";

    return $this->content;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea to mix php and html in this way. You would be happier with a template engine..

Comment: This reminds me of a cartoon from a couple of years back... something like: _"Check out the browser I just wrote, it renders the divs exactly the way I want it"_ answer: _"Don't you think there's already enough decent browser out there?"_ reply: _"Wait until you've seen the OS on which I run my browser"_... Bottom line: You're reinventing the wheel, and it's pear-shaped. [Perhaps use the already existing `DOMDocument` class](http://www.php.net/DOMDocument)

Comment: Reinventing the wheel isn't my goal. With a template you would suggest to create the 'section' (<article>) and replace the content & title on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

in the end I went with the suggest/remark of @redreggae and focussed on creating a template for this solution.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe an option is to use/take inspiration from [Html](http://doc.nette.org/en/html-elements) class from Nette framework.